# Why doesn't this piece of JavaScript code work when placed inside <head> but works when placed at the bottom of <body>

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I was trying to write this basic JavaScript program which changes the background color when a button is pressed.

When I place this JS code inside the 'head' tags it does NOT work but when I place it inside the 'body' tag it does. (When placing inside body I removed `window.onload`)

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
var para = document.getElementById("para");

function togglecolor(){
    if(para.className != "yellow") para.className = "yellow";
    else para.className = "notYellow";
}
}
</script>
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<h1 id="para" class="">Hello World! </h1>
<button onClick="togglecolor();">Press Me</button>
```

I am unable to understand why it does not work when places inside 'head'.

Comment: Try to define togglecolor() in the global namespace, not in window.onload.

Comment: ...and pass `para` to togglecolor() as an argument.

Comment: @user603003 yeah...that works. Can you tell why?

Comment: @mblase75 It actually does NOT work when I pass para as an argument.

Comment: Jatin, see my answer for why @user603003's comment works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a scope issue.  You are defining your function within another function.  This means it is only accessible inside that function.  Move it outside and everything should work.

```
<script>
function togglecolor(){
    var para = document.getElementById("para");
    if(para.className != "yellow") para.className = "yellow";
    else para.className = "notYellow";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of the fact that h1 tag with id="para" is not yet loaded when the javascript was executed

Comment: but I have used window.onload to take care of that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you have defined `toggleColor` method inside `window` load event hanlder. Try to move it out and try it putting the code inside head.

```
<script>
function togglecolor(){
    var para = document.getElementById("para")
    if(para.className != "yellow") 
        para.className = "yellow";
    else 
        para.className = "notYellow";
}
window.onload = togglecolor;
</script>
```

Comment: This is the problem.  Only thing I would point out, he's not actually calling the function on load.

Comment: @kingjiv When using  window.onload = togglecolor;  isn't the function getting called?

Comment: @Jatin - It will not call the function when you set that way. It will be called when `load` event is triggered by the browser.

Comment: Yeah! I misinterpreted @kingjiv 's comment.

Answer (score -1):

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ea6d3/3

works. change `window.onload` to `$(function(){`

```
<html>
<body>
<style>
.yellow {color:yellow;}
.notYellow {color:blue;}
</style>
<script>
function togglecolor(){
        var para = document.getElementById("para");
        if(para.className != "yellow") 
             para.className = "yellow";
        else para.className = "notYellow";
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="para" class="notYellow">Hello World! </h1>
<button onClick="togglecolor();">Press Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure about wrong, but it does seem a bit odd.  Not sure why you would put `document.ready` within the function.  It's uneeded.  The function doesn't get called until the button is clicked.  At that point para will exist.

Answer (score -2):

The reason is probably due to your placement of the script. When a script is loaded, it is run at that point; ergo, if you have a html file like so:

```
 <html>
   <head />
   <body>
     <script />
     <h1 />
     <button />
   </body>
 </html>
```

The script file is going to be run, then the rest of the page will continue to load. Because you have the assignment of `para` occuring outside the context of your `togglecolor` function, it obtains it's value when loaded; potentially before the actual HTML element has been loaded.

Comment: This would be true except that he's got his code inside `window.onload`.

Comment: It works when he put it in the head tag because it's invoked on load; when it's in the body tag, he took it out of the onload event.